# Cleaning ground rotor magnets dust and particles after rotor assembly damage

Tags: motorcycle, engine-theory, contamination

I happen to have an FZ8 motorcycle which is famous in warmer climates like Greece for a very serious failure (along with FZ1 and R1) in the rotor assembly.
In many cases the glue holding the magnets in place in older rotors (models 2008-2014) tends to fail resulting one or more magnets dropping between the rotating rotor and the coils and get ground up into a fine dust. 
Regardless of HOW MUCH DANGEROUS THIS IS (leads to engine stall, smashes coil etc) if we assume this failure occurred in a way with no real damage on the motorcycle and just ended with ground up magnet dust all over my engine. How serious would this be?

Would magnet dust penetrate in "bad" places"?
Would it magnetize metallic areas in the engine leading to increased friction etc? (http://www.bussi-demagnetizers.com/en/electronic-impulse-demagnetizers/causes-and-consequences-of-residual-magnetism-in-metal-machining)
How could someone clean this mess???

EDIT:
I only need to assess the level of cleaning that should occur afterwards. Should someone just remove visible pieces and drain/replace oil and oil filter or a more meticulous cleaning should take place by disassembling the whole engine and cleaning each part?
Though here there is evidence that magnetized rubbing surfaces have less wear (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/004316489390501C)

Comment: About 5 questions here, could you refine what you would like to achieve with your post.

Comment: I would have thought a powerful magnet could be used to pull the powder off any metal parts.